# jquery ui draggable in rotated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, draggable

i have a child div in a container div, the container div rotated 30 degrees, the child div is a draggable element. but the drag behavior is not correct.

html:

```
<div id="container" class="r30">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  #container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: yellow;
  }

  #child {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: black;
  }

  .r30 {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
```

js:

```
$("#child").draggable();
```

or jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wuminzhe/GEruH/

Answer (score 0):

You should use $("#child").draggable({containment: $("#container")});